# C# 4.0 Winforms Book

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Can any one recommend me a good book for Winforms in .net 4.0 C#. Generally I prefer reading Wrox books as they teach by making something (Recently read ASP.Net book where they followed the entire tutorial by making a website) but they don't have a special Winforms book I think. A book with some application making example will be great but still any book with good knowledge will work perfect.

I can read about forms and controls directly from internet but that's the reason I am looking for a book with some application examples.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book Recommendation for Winforms Design & Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357545/book-recommendation-for-winforms-design-programming)

Comment: What did you choose? and since you mention you're after a new technology now, did you choose WPF?

Comment: Its my personal opinion. I feel WPF will not be able to make things big. I chose Web technology (ASP.Net) rather. But honestly, I am still in Winforms. But soon will get a chance to shift in my present company in Web technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's basically nothing significant changed in WinForms through .NET versions. Updates are more maintenance, bugfixes, visual style updates and compatibility with new OSs. You can see that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bece079c-9af4-465a-b0e7-eb54cb30ae25) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696932/187955). Even update from .NET 2 to .NET 3.5 was maintenance (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762963.aspx)).

If you're still after a WinForms book, I think [Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594398) is a good one. It's more advanced than going through steps of creating a desktop application. But most books on WinForms will be as it's simpler subject than ASP.NET.

If you're trying to stay current with development try reading about Silverlight or WPF.

Answer (score 0):

@rapsalands this book **[Windows Forms Programming in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321116208)** is a good one to start with WinForms. I got a copy of it when I started learn the BCL (precisely the UI libraries).

Note: It is a old book, but it can redirect you to an interesting material to get update or to extend some particular topic.

Comment: Thanks John. But my post is a bit old. Actually now I am in a process of ditching Winforms and taking up a new technology :)